# Why do we use next() function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Do we use it only in middlewares or the functions with no routes? I have used it in my authentication file...

```
function ensureAuthenticated(req, res, next){
if(req.isAuthenticated()){
    return next();
  } else {
    req.flash('error_msg' , 'Please login First...')
    res.redirect('/users/login');
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Linux. if this or any other answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this, however, this is the way for community to identify the answers that solved the question.

Answer (score 3):

You execute it in order to execute the next middleware in the pipe. If you don't execute it manually, you're probably passing it on to a different module that executes it for you. Otherwise, if you don't execute `next`, you cut the "pipe" short i.e. yours is the last middleware that runs.

In your case it makes perfect sense to call `next()` when the user is authenticated. That passes the control to the next piece of middleware. It also makes sense not to call `next()` in the case that you've already established that the user is not authenticated, since in most cases you don't want the rest of the middleware in the "pipe" to execute.

So yes, `next()` is used by middleware, or modules intended to be called by middleware.

I hope that answers your question.

Answer (score 3):

If you talking about Express framework here - `next` function is just a callback telling that this particular middleware handler should execute next operation in Express middleware chain.

If you define any handler with signature `someHandler(req, res, next)` and register it with `app.use`, it will become a part of that chain. Essentially it just a special callback function - disregarding the purpose of the function itself - route controller, authentication, body parser, etc.